# How to change style of the last row in a listview in Xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

for a giving list to be shown in a **`ListView`**, how can I target the last row to edit its style?

Comment: You can use DataTemplateSelector for your requirement. but you need to add one more property for identify last row in model (ListView Item binding model) like boolean IsLast.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/

Comment: try to use footer for the listview

Comment: @MikeDarwish Do you still have any questions?

Comment: @PavanVParekh I am getting the data from Json from the server, I can not add IsLast to the object

Comment: @MikeDarwish I can not use a footer because I an using ContextAction on the list, so the footer will not get access to the ContextAction

Comment: @Mohanad you can modify your json data via LINQ.

Comment: @PavanVParekh I am a noob actually , what is  that?

Comment: @Mohanad, You can add one field/property like: 
public bool IsLast { get; set; }
in your model. and after receiving data from server, Modify your response via LINQ query like:
ResponseList.LastOrDefault()?.IsLast = true;

Now you can easily use "DataTemplateSelector" (base on this IsLast value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use **Footer**

  ```
  <ListView.Footer>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Footer" TextColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="Blue" />
     </StackLayout>
  </ListView.Footer>
  ```
- use **DataTemplateSelector**

  sample [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/templates/datatemplateselector/), and change something in that project

  1.In `Person` ,add a bool property which can be dealed as the last row , and change its constructor function:

  ```
  public bool IsLastRow { get; set; }

  public Person (string name, DateTime dob, string location , bool isLastRow)
  {
      Name = name;
      DateOfBirth = dob;
      Location = location;
      IsLastRow = false;
      IsLastRow = isLastRow;
  }
  ```

  2.In `HomePage` ,set value for the model list.

  ```
   var people = new List<Person> {
          new Person ("Kath", new DateTime (1985, 11, 20), "France" ,false),
          new Person ("Steve", new DateTime (1975, 1, 15), "USA",false),
          new Person ("Lucas", new DateTime (1988, 2, 5), "Germany",false),
          new Person ("John", new DateTime (1976, 2, 20), "USA",false),
          new Person ("Tariq", new DateTime (1987, 1, 10), "UK",false),
          new Person ("Jane", new DateTime (1982, 8, 30), "USA",false),
          new Person ("Tom", new DateTime (1977, 3, 10), "UK",true)
      };
  ```

  3.In `PersonDataTemplateSelector` ,modify the method which decides the template

  ```
  protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate (object item, BindableObject container)
  {
      return ((Person)item).IsLastRow ? ValidTemplate : InvalidTemplate;
  }
  ```

result:[image]

### **Edit:**

if you get the list from the json data, then you should go through the list and add the isLastRow to object manually in **Step2**.
Like this:

```
int index = 0;
foreach(Person person in list){
     person.isLastRow = (index == list.Count-1);
     index ++;
}
```

Comment: Actually I am getting the list from Json data, so I can not add IsLastRow to the object

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks